# Log4j2 not able to apply pattern layout %replace feature more than 2 times in sequence

Tags: regex, slf4j, log4j2, pattern-layout

```
%replace{%replace{%replace{%msg}{regex1}{substitution1}}{regex2}{substitution2}}{regex3}{substitution3}
```

I'm trying to replace the regex pattern from my log and it works properly. 
When `%replace` is used at max twice, but when I try to replace the third pattern it stops working and it just prints "`%replace` " in log output.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
<Pattern>"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %replace{%replace{%replace{%msg}{reg1}{sub1}}{reg2}{sub2}}{reg3}{sub3}%n"</Pattern>
```